# React Native List Component that looks like iOS native lists

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Does anybody know if there is any **built-in** React Native component that render lists like this?

[image]

Comment: You can use a SectionList -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/section-list

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be super hard to implement this from scratch
If you want the exactly same design there are probably three or so components that you need to write

Heres pseudo code

```
const settings = [
{
 items : [{
 icon : SomeIcon,
 label : "Notifications",
 action: () => ...navigate somewhere
},
...more items

]
}
]
...more code

return
 <FlatList>
    {settings.map(setting =>{
      return <SettingSection>
         {setting.items.map(item =>{
           return <Item/>

          })

          }
           </SettingSection>
         })}
      </FlatList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it by yourself but if you want exactly the same view, here i found a npm package for you. **https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-settings-list** . it is efficient and customizable.